# filtering an array based on elements not available in another array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects arr1 which has a property widgetId which i am interested in. my intention is to filter arr1 based on ids which are not present in arr2. my arrays are as follows

```
 arr1= [
     
        {
            "widgetId": 2,
            "widgetKey": "totalSales_card_cash",
            "widgetName": "Total Sales Birfurcated Card & Cash",
            "title": "Sales Report",
            "type": "chart",
            "chartType": "pie",
       
            "filters": {
                "sortBy": "lastYear",
                "appliedFilters": {
                    "startDate": "2022-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00",
                    "endDate": "2022-12-31T23:59:59.999+00:00"
                }
            },
            "showDefault": false,
            "isLive": true
        },
        {
            "widgetId": 3,
            "widgetKey": "totalSales_perishablesNonPerisablesHotMeals",
            "widgetName": "Total Sales Birfurcated perishables/non-perishables/hot meals and beverage",
            "title": "Sales Report",
            "type": "chart",
            "chartType": "pie",
            "displayType": "oneColumn",

            "filters": {
                "sortBy": "lastYear",
                "appliedFilters": {
                    "startDate": "2022-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00",
                    "endDate": "2022-12-31T23:59:59.999+00:00"
                }
            },
            "showDefault": false,
            "isLive": true
        },
        {
            "widgetId": 5,
            "widgetKey": "totalSales_dayWise",
            "widgetName": "Day wise bar chart",
            "title": "Total Sales: DayWise",
            "type": "chart",
            "chartType": "bar",
            "displayType": "oneColumn",

            "filters": {
                "endDate": "2021-11-30T00:00:00+05:30",
                "startDate": "2021-10-01T00:00:00+05:30",
                "sortBy": "betweenDates",
                "appliedFilters": {
                    "endDate": "2021-11-29T18:30:00.000+00:00",
                    "startDate": "2021-09-30T18:30:00.000+00:00",
                    "sortBy": "betweenDates"
                }
            },
            "showDefault": false,
            "options": {
                "scales": {
                    "x": {
                        "grid": {
                            "color": "#ffffff1f"
                        }
                    },
                    "y": {
                        "beginAtZero": false,
                        "grid": {
                            "color": "#ffffff1f"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "plugins": {
                    "legend": {
                        "display": false
                    },
                    "title": {
                        "text": "Total Sales: DayWise",
                        "display": false
                    }
                }
            },
            "isLive": true
        },
        {
            "widgetId": 6,
            "widgetKey": "totalSales_monthWise",
            "widgetName": "Month wise bar chart",
            "title": "Total Sales: MonthWise",
            "type": "chart",
            "chartType": "bar",
            "displayType": "oneColumn",
  
            "filters": {
                "sortBy": "lastYear",
                "appliedFilters": {
                    "sortBy": "lastYear",
                    "startDate": "2022-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00",
                    "endDate": "2022-12-31T23:59:59.999+00:00"
                }
            },
            "showDefault": true,
            "options": {
                "scales": {
                    "x": {
                        "grid": {
                            "color": "#ffffff1f"
                        }
                    },
                    "y": {
                        "beginAtZero": false,
                        "grid": {
                            "color": "#ffffff1f"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "plugins": {
                    "legend": {
                        "display": false
                    },
                    "title": {
                        "text": "Total Sales: MonthWise",
                        "display": false
                    }
                }
            },
            "isLive": true
        },
        {
            "widgetId": 7,
            "widgetKey": "totalSales_currencyWise",
            "widgetName": "Total Sales currency wise",
            "title": "Total Sales currency wise",
            "type": "chart",
            "chartType": "bar",
            "displayType": "oneColumn",
      
            "filters": {
                "endDate": "2021-11-30T00:00:00+05:30",
                "startDate": "2021-11-01T00:00:00+05:30",
                "sortBy": "betweenDates",
                "appliedFilters": {
                    "startDate": "2021-10-31T18:30:00.000+00:00",
                    "endDate": "2021-11-29T18:30:00.000+00:00"
                }
            },
            "showDefault": false,
            "options": {
                "scales": {
                    "x": {
                        "grid": {
                            "color": "#ffffff1f"
                        }
                    },
                    "y": {
                        "beginAtZero": false,
                        "grid": {
                            "color": "#ffffff1f"
                        },
                        "ticks": {
                            "stepSize": 100000
                        }
                    }
                },
                "animation": false,
                "plugins": {
                    "legend": {
                        "display": false
                    },
                    "title": {
                        "text": "Total Sales Currency Wise",
                        "display": false
                    }
                }
            },
            "isLive": true
        },
        {
            "widgetId": 8,
            "widgetKey": "totalSales_baseWise",
            "widgetName": "Total Sales: BaseWise",
            "title": "Total Sales: BaseWise",
            "type": "chart",
            "chartType": "bar",
            "displayType": "oneColumn",
    
            "filters": {
                "endDate": "2022-11-30T00:00:00+05:30",
                "startDate": "2021-11-01T00:00:00+05:30",
                "sortBy": "betweenDates",
                "appliedFilters": {
                    "startDate": "2021-10-31T18:30:00.000+00:00",
                    "endDate": "2022-11-29T18:30:00.000+00:00"
                }
            },
            "showDefault": true,
            "options": {
                "scales": {
                    "x": {
                        "grid": {
                            "color": "#ffffff1f"
                        }
                    },
                    "y": {
                        "beginAtZero": false,
                        "grid": {
                            "color": "#ffffff1f"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "plugins": {
                    "legend": {
                        "display": false
                    },
                    "title": {
                        "text": "Total Sales: BaseWise",
                        "display": false
                    }
                }
            },
            "isLive": true
        },
        {
            "widgetId": 9,
            "widgetKey": "declinedCardAmount",
            "widgetName": "Declined Card amount per day",
            "title": "Declined Card amount per day",
            "type": "chart",
            "chartType": "bar",
            "displayType": "oneColumn",

            "filters": {
                "endDate": "2021-11-07T00:00:00+05:30",
                "startDate": "2021-11-01T00:00:00+05:30",
                "sortBy": "betweenDates",
                "appliedFilters": {
                    "startDate": "2021-10-31T18:30:00.000+00:00",
                    "endDate": "2021-11-06T18:30:00.000+00:00"
                }
            },
            "showDefault": false,
            "options": {
                "scales": {
                    "x": {
                        "beginAtZero": false,
                        "grid": {
                            "color": " #ffffff1f"
                        }
                    },
                    "y": {
                        "beginAtZero": false,
                        "grid": {
                            "color": "#ffffff1f"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "responsive": true,
                "plugins": {
                    "legend": {
                        "display": false
                    },
                    "title": {
                        "text": "Declined Card Amount Per Day",
                        "display": false
                    }
                }
            },
            "isLive": true
        },

        {
            "widgetId": 11,
            "widgetKey": "physicalQTY_productSale_warehouseWise",
            "widgetName": "Physical quantity of products sale warehouse wise",
            "title": "Sales Report",
            "type": "listView",
            "chartType": "",
            "displayType": "twoColumns",
    
            "filters": {
                "warehouseId": "1",
                "appliedFilters": {
                    "warehouseId": 1
                }
            },
            "showDefault": false,
            "isLive": true
        },
        {
            "widgetId": 12,
            "widgetKey": "orderSalesCurrentFinancialYear",
            "widgetName": "Sales and orders of current financial year",
            "title": "Sales and orders of current financial year",
            "type": "card",
            "chartType": "",
            "displayType": "oneColumn",
         
        
            "filters": {
                "sortBy": "thisYear",
                "appliedFilters": {}
            },
            "showDefault": false,
            "isLive": true
        },
        {
            "widgetId": 13,
            "widgetKey": "currentMonthAvgSalesOrders",
            "widgetName": "Current month average sales and orders",
            "title": "Current month average sales and orders",
            "type": "card",
            "chartType": "",
            "displayType": "oneColumn",
         
           
            "filters": {
                "sortBy": "thisMonth",
                "appliedFilters": {}
            },
            "showDefault": true,
            "isLive": true
        },
        {
            "widgetId": 14,
            "widgetKey": "mostDeclinedCardSectorsPerMonthWeek",
            "widgetName": "Most declined card sectors per month/week",
            "title": "cards sectors",
            "type": "listView",
            "chartType": "list",
            "displayType": "twoColumns",
            
            "filters": {
                "sortBy": "thisWeek"
            },
            "showDefault": false
        },
  
      
        {
            "widgetId": 17,
            "widgetKey": "totalDeposit",
            "widgetName": "Total deposit",
            "title": "Deposits total",
            "type": "listView",
            "chartType": "list",
            "displayType": "twoColumns",
           
            "filters": {
                "sortBy": "thisWeek"
            },
            "showDefault": false
        },

        {
            "widgetId": 35,
            "widgetKey": "avgWastage",
            "widgetName": "Average Wastage for the financial year",
            "title": "Average Wastage for the financial year",
            "type": "chart",
            "chartType": "line",
            "displayType": "oneColumn",
            "legends": [
                {
                    "color": "#63ABFD",
                    "name": "Dataset 1"
                },
                {
                    "color": "#9B5A97",
                    "name": "Dataset 2"
                }
            ],
            "datasets": [
                {
                    "backgroundColor": "#63ABFD",
                    "borderColor": "#63ABFD",
                    "data": [
                        4000,
                        2000,
                        1000,
                        2000,
                        1000,
                        4000,
                        1000,
                        2000,
                        1000,
                        1000,
                        2000,
                        3000
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "backgroundColor": "#9B5A97",
                    "borderColor": "#9B5A97",
                    "data": [
                        1000,
                        3000,
                        2000,
                        1300,
                        1000,
                        2000,
                        2000,
                        3000,
                        1000,
                        2000,
                        3000,
                        2000,
                        8000,
                        1000
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "filters": {
                "sortBy": "thisWeek"
            },
            "showDefault": false,
            "options": {
                "plugins": {
                    "title": {
                        "display": false,
                        "text": "Total Sales Currency Wise"
                    },
                    "legend": {
                        "display": false
                    }
                },
                "animation": false,
                "scales": {
                    "y": {
                        "ticks": {
                            "stepSize": 100000
                        },
                        "grid": {
                            "color": "#ffffff1f"
                        },
                        "beginAtZero": false
                    },
                    "x": {
                        "grid": {
                            "color": "#ffffff1f"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]

arr2=[6,24,8,9,14,11,17]
```

i should get a array which doesn't have elements in arr2 ie the widgetId in arr1 and it should add a property selected:false in each object in arr1 which doesn't include arr2 values as widgetId.

i have tried the code below

```
const filterByIdArray = (arr2, arr1) =>
   arr1.filter(item =>
        arr2.find(i =>
        i !== item.widgetId));
```

but it doesn't seems to give me the desired result .what can be done to implement this?

Comment: What is the expected output here?

Answer (score 0):

`find` will return the first element in arr2 which !== item.widgetId, its not a boolean, so the filter won't do anything.

Try `includes`.

```js
const filterByIdArray = (arr2, arr1) => arr1.filter((item) => !arr2.includes(item.widgetId));
```

Set `selected` by `element["selected"] = false;` and push it to new array.

```js
let res = [];
filterByIdArray(arr2, arr1).forEach((element) => {
  element["selected"] = false;
  res.push(element);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use negation of `includes` and `map` with spread operator to set `seleted` property to false

```js
const arr1 = [
     
        {
            "widgetId": 2,
            "widgetKey": "totalSales_card_cash",
            "widgetName": "Total Sales Birfurcated Card & Cash",
            "title": "Sales Report",
            "type": "chart",
            "chartType": "pie",
       
            "filters": {
                "sortBy": "lastYear",
                "appliedFilters": {
                    "startDate": "2022-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00",
                    "endDate": "2022-12-31T23:59:59.999+00:00"
                }
            },
            "showDefault": false,
            "isLive": true
        },
        {
            "widgetId": 3,
            "widgetKey": "totalSales_perishablesNonPerisablesHotMeals",
            "widgetName": "Total Sales Birfurcated perishables/non-perishables/hot meals and beverage",
            "title": "Sales Report",
            "type": "chart",
            "chartType": "pie",
            "displayType": "oneColumn",

            "filters": {
                "sortBy": "lastYear",
                "appliedFilters": {
                    "startDate": "2022-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00",
                    "endDate": "2022-12-31T23:59:59.999+00:00"
                }
            },
            "showDefault": false,
            "isLive": true
        },
        {
            "widgetId": 5,
            "widgetKey": "totalSales_dayWise",
            "widgetName": "Day wise bar chart",
            "title": "Total Sales: DayWise",
            "type": "chart",
            "chartType": "bar",
            "displayType": "oneColumn",

            "filters": {
                "endDate": "2021-11-30T00:00:00+05:30",
                "startDate": "2021-10-01T00:00:00+05:30",
                "sortBy": "betweenDates",
                "appliedFilters": {
                    "endDate": "2021-11-29T18:30:00.000+00:00",
                    "startDate": "2021-09-30T18:30:00.000+00:00",
                    "sortBy": "betweenDates"
                }
            },
            "showDefault": false,
            "options": {
                "scales": {
                    "x": {
                        "grid": {
                            "color": "#ffffff1f"
                        }
                    },
                    "y": {
                        "beginAtZero": false,
                        "grid": {
                            "color": "#ffffff1f"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "plugins": {
                    "legend": {
                        "display": false
                    },
                    "title": {
                        "text": "Total Sales: DayWise",
                        "display": false
                    }
                }
            },
            "isLive": true
        },
        {
            "widgetId": 6,
            "widgetKey": "totalSales_monthWise",
            "widgetName": "Month wise bar chart",
            "title": "Total Sales: MonthWise",
            "type": "chart",
            "chartType": "bar",
            "displayType": "oneColumn",
  
            "filters": {
                "sortBy": "lastYear",
                "appliedFilters": {
                    "sortBy": "lastYear",
                    "startDate": "2022-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00",
                    "endDate": "2022-12-31T23:59:59.999+00:00"
                }
            },
            "showDefault": true,
            "options": {
                "scales": {
                    "x": {
                        "grid": {
                            "color": "#ffffff1f"
                        }
                    },
                    "y": {
                        "beginAtZero": false,
                        "grid": {
                            "color": "#ffffff1f"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "plugins": {
                    "legend": {
                        "display": false
                    },
                    "title": {
                        "text": "Total Sales: MonthWise",
                        "display": false
                    }
                }
            },
            "isLive": true
        },
        {
            "widgetId": 7,
            "widgetKey": "totalSales_currencyWise",
            "widgetName": "Total Sales currency wise",
            "title": "Total Sales currency wise",
            "type": "chart",
            "chartType": "bar",
            "displayType": "oneColumn",
      
            "filters": {
                "endDate": "2021-11-30T00:00:00+05:30",
                "startDate": "2021-11-01T00:00:00+05:30",
                "sortBy": "betweenDates",
                "appliedFilters": {
                    "startDate": "2021-10-31T18:30:00.000+00:00",
                    "endDate": "2021-11-29T18:30:00.000+00:00"
                }
            },
            "showDefault": false,
            "options": {
                "scales": {
                    "x": {
                        "grid": {
                            "color": "#ffffff1f"
                        }
                    },
                    "y": {
                        "beginAtZero": false,
                        "grid": {
                            "color": "#ffffff1f"
                        },
                        "ticks": {
                            "stepSize": 100000
                        }
                    }
                },
                "animation": false,
                "plugins": {
                    "legend": {
                        "display": false
                    },
                    "title": {
                        "text": "Total Sales Currency Wise",
                        "display": false
                    }
                }
            },
            "isLive": true
        },
        {
            "widgetId": 8,
            "widgetKey": "totalSales_baseWise",
            "widgetName": "Total Sales: BaseWise",
            "title": "Total Sales: BaseWise",
            "type": "chart",
            "chartType": "bar",
            "displayType": "oneColumn",
    
            "filters": {
                "endDate": "2022-11-30T00:00:00+05:30",
                "startDate": "2021-11-01T00:00:00+05:30",
                "sortBy": "betweenDates",
                "appliedFilters": {
                    "startDate": "2021-10-31T18:30:00.000+00:00",
                    "endDate": "2022-11-29T18:30:00.000+00:00"
                }
            },
            "showDefault": true,
            "options": {
                "scales": {
                    "x": {
                        "grid": {
                            "color": "#ffffff1f"
                        }
                    },
                    "y": {
                        "beginAtZero": false,
                        "grid": {
                            "color": "#ffffff1f"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "plugins": {
                    "legend": {
                        "display": false
                    },
                    "title": {
                        "text": "Total Sales: BaseWise",
                        "display": false
                    }
                }
            },
            "isLive": true
        },
        {
            "widgetId": 9,
            "widgetKey": "declinedCardAmount",
            "widgetName": "Declined Card amount per day",
            "title": "Declined Card amount per day",
            "type": "chart",
            "chartType": "bar",
            "displayType": "oneColumn",

            "filters": {
                "endDate": "2021-11-07T00:00:00+05:30",
                "startDate": "2021-11-01T00:00:00+05:30",
                "sortBy": "betweenDates",
                "appliedFilters": {
                    "startDate": "2021-10-31T18:30:00.000+00:00",
                    "endDate": "2021-11-06T18:30:00.000+00:00"
                }
            },
            "showDefault": false,
            "options": {
                "scales": {
                    "x": {
                        "beginAtZero": false,
                        "grid": {
                            "color": " #ffffff1f"
                        }
                    },
                    "y": {
                        "beginAtZero": false,
                        "grid": {
                            "color": "#ffffff1f"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "responsive": true,
                "plugins": {
                    "legend": {
                        "display": false
                    },
                    "title": {
                        "text": "Declined Card Amount Per Day",
                        "display": false
                    }
                }
            },
            "isLive": true
        },

        {
            "widgetId": 11,
            "widgetKey": "physicalQTY_productSale_warehouseWise",
            "widgetName": "Physical quantity of products sale warehouse wise",
            "title": "Sales Report",
            "type": "listView",
            "chartType": "",
            "displayType": "twoColumns",
    
            "filters": {
                "warehouseId": "1",
                "appliedFilters": {
                    "warehouseId": 1
                }
            },
            "showDefault": false,
            "isLive": true
        },
        {
            "widgetId": 12,
            "widgetKey": "orderSalesCurrentFinancialYear",
            "widgetName": "Sales and orders of current financial year",
            "title": "Sales and orders of current financial year",
            "type": "card",
            "chartType": "",
            "displayType": "oneColumn",
         
        
            "filters": {
                "sortBy": "thisYear",
                "appliedFilters": {}
            },
            "showDefault": false,
            "isLive": true
        },
        {
            "widgetId": 13,
            "widgetKey": "currentMonthAvgSalesOrders",
            "widgetName": "Current month average sales and orders",
            "title": "Current month average sales and orders",
            "type": "card",
            "chartType": "",
            "displayType": "oneColumn",
         
           
            "filters": {
                "sortBy": "thisMonth",
                "appliedFilters": {}
            },
            "showDefault": true,
            "isLive": true
        },
        {
            "widgetId": 14,
            "widgetKey": "mostDeclinedCardSectorsPerMonthWeek",
            "widgetName": "Most declined card sectors per month/week",
            "title": "cards sectors",
            "type": "listView",
            "chartType": "list",
            "displayType": "twoColumns",
            
            "filters": {
                "sortBy": "thisWeek"
            },
            "showDefault": false
        },
  
      
        {
            "widgetId": 17,
            "widgetKey": "totalDeposit",
            "widgetName": "Total deposit",
            "title": "Deposits total",
            "type": "listView",
            "chartType": "list",
            "displayType": "twoColumns",
           
            "filters": {
                "sortBy": "thisWeek"
            },
            "showDefault": false
        },

        {
            "widgetId": 35,
            "widgetKey": "avgWastage",
            "widgetName": "Average Wastage for the financial year",
            "title": "Average Wastage for the financial year",
            "type": "chart",
            "chartType": "line",
            "displayType": "oneColumn",
            "legends": [
                {
                    "color": "#63ABFD",
                    "name": "Dataset 1"
                },
                {
                    "color": "#9B5A97",
                    "name": "Dataset 2"
                }
            ],
            "datasets": [
                {
                    "backgroundColor": "#63ABFD",
                    "borderColor": "#63ABFD",
                    "data": [
                        4000,
                        2000,
                        1000,
                        2000,
                        1000,
                        4000,
                        1000,
                        2000,
                        1000,
                        1000,
                        2000,
                        3000
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "backgroundColor": "#9B5A97",
                    "borderColor": "#9B5A97",
                    "data": [
                        1000,
                        3000,
                        2000,
                        1300,
                        1000,
                        2000,
                        2000,
                        3000,
                        1000,
                        2000,
                        3000,
                        2000,
                        8000,
                        1000
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "filters": {
                "sortBy": "thisWeek"
            },
            "showDefault": false,
            "options": {
                "plugins": {
                    "title": {
                        "display": false,
                        "text": "Total Sales Currency Wise"
                    },
                    "legend": {
                        "display": false
                    }
                },
                "animation": false,
                "scales": {
                    "y": {
                        "ticks": {
                            "stepSize": 100000
                        },
                        "grid": {
                            "color": "#ffffff1f"
                        },
                        "beginAtZero": false
                    },
                    "x": {
                        "grid": {
                            "color": "#ffffff1f"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]

const arr2=[6,24,8,9,14,11,17]

const filterByIdArray = (arr2, arr1) =>
  arr1.filter(item => !arr2.includes(item.widgetId))
      .map(item => ({ ...item, selected: false }));



const filteredArray = filterByIdArray(arr2, arr1);
console.log(filteredArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

a way to do that..

```js
const filterByIdArray = (arr1,arr2) =>
  {
  let res = arr1.filter(({widgetId}) => !arr2.includes(widgetId));
      res.forEach( elm => elm.selected = false );
  return res;
  }
 
// simplified testing 
const arr1 = 
    [ { widgetId :  2, otherdata : '...' } 
    , { widgetId :  3 } 
    , { widgetId :  5 } 
    , { widgetId :  6 } 
    , { widgetId :  7 } 
    , { widgetId :  8 } 
    , { widgetId :  9 } 
    , { widgetId : 11 } 
    , { widgetId : 13 } 
    , { widgetId : 14 } 
    , { widgetId : 17 } 
    , { widgetId : 35 } 
    ] 
, arr2 = [ 6, 24, 8, 9, 14, 11, 17 ]
  ;
  
console.log( filterByIdArray(arr1,arr2) );
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
.as-console-row::after {display: none !important;}
```